# How can i display Dialog box over locked screen like viber or Line messenger

Tags: android, dialog, wakelock, screen-lock

I need to display a dialog box that displays irrespective of the user screen locked or in deep sleep. My current scenario is :

1. **Broadcast receiver**  Initiates **Service** and acquires WakeLock

   PowerManager
           mgr=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
           lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                   LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
2. **Service** starts an **Activity** with following settings

   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); 
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                     | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
3. **Activity** starts a **DialogFragment**

The problem is that dialog doesn't appear if screen is locked or in sleep. The Message dialogs in Viber app and Line messenger apps popups even if screen is off or locked. How they do it ?

**Edit**

Well i found out that it works when activity theme is set to **Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen** or Any FULLSCREEN theme. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

These flags worked for me after i changed my Activity theme to

```
Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [KeyGuardManage](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)r to unlock the device automatically and then acquire your Wake Lock.

```
    KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean isKeyguardUp = kgm.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
KeyguardLock kgl = kgm.newKeyguardLock("Your Activity/Service name");

if(isKeyguardUp){
kgl.disableKeyguard();
isKeyguardUp = false;
}

wl.acquire(); //use your wake lock once keyguard is down.
```

Comment: newKeyguardLock and disableKeyguard methods are deprecated now. And will it work if screen is locked with password or pattern ?

Comment: Use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED instead; If screen is locked with password or pattern I m not sure about it

Comment: Well i found out that These flags work with FullScreen Activity. Worked for me, earlier i was using Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth . But now i changed theme of the Activity to "Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" and it works :)

Comment: does It work with screen locked with password and pattern update if it works or any solution u find

Comment: yes it works with sceen locked with patterns as well